# vb.net parsing json

Tags: vb.net, json, parsing, twitter

How can I parse json from such as twitter etc in vb.net applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DataContractJsonSerializer class of the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace.  You can use it's ReadObject method to deserialize the JSON stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSon.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library. I've never used it from VB.net but I assume it's CLS-compliant and it should work OK.